# Making a multicolored TextBox?

Tags: c++, user-interface

I noticed that Windows's RichTextBox supports making the selected text any color. I'm trying to get a better understanding of how it might be doing this at a low level. Could it be storing each char's color, or might there be a better way (since removal and random insertion must be considered.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stores the text in the [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) format.